# How to exclude results for certain words like "West Virgina" when searching for "Virginia" in a US state list?

Tags: solr

I've got SOLR happily running indexing a list of department names that contain US states. It is working well however, searching for "Virginia" will turn up results containing "West Virginia", and while certainly helpful for some business requirements, is not in ours.

Is there a special way of saying that a query for X must not contain Y (I don't mind crafting a special query for the case of "Virginia"), or can I only do this post-query by iterating over the results and excluding results with "West Virginia"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a minus sign (hyphen) combined with the phrases/terms you want to exclude. If you use the dismax query parser, then you don't even need to specify field names.

Examples:

using dismax:

```
q=virginia -"west virginia"
```

using standard query parser:

```
q=field_name:(virginia -"west virginia")
```

Refer to the [Solr Query Syntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) wiki page and its further links for more examples.

Comment: How about multiple keywords like ignoring "west virginia" and "califronia" if q=states

Answer (score 0):

You could make a state field that is a string type and just search on state:"virginia"  (lowercase the string before indexing / searching)