# How to query for a word in Solr ignoring a combination with it?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a working Solr with a lot of documents in it. My problem is that I don't find a way to query for a specific word like `Switzerland`, but don't want to find documents containing the combination `Saxon Switzerland` except they contain `Switzerland` without the preceding `Saxon`.

A similar question already got asked [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042009/how-to-exclude-results-for-certain-words-like-west-virgina-when-searching-for/13043363), but the solution to query `Switzerland -"Saxon Switzerland"` would not work as the documents containing both would be missing.

I don't want to exclude the phrase, but ignore it for matching. But it seems that there is no possibility to partially negate or ignore a phrase or proximity search. Is there any possibility to search for something like `Switzerland {ignore}"Saxon Switzerland"`? Or can you exclude phrases from matching at all? (only for a single query as the phrase might be of interest for other queries)

Comment: Your requirement (matching documents containing "foo" not preceded by "bar") would need a negative look-behind assertion. It could be achieved using a regular expression, a RegexpQuery which the standard query parser can handle (defType=lucene), provided that the field is not tokenized (and not too big for performance).

Comment: That would be an interesting solution. Unfortunately I got documents in my index which are very long (texts of PDFs with over 100 pages), so I need something which works on tokenized fields.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore "saxon" From "Switzerland"

Try below Query .
**text:'NOT(saxon) AND Switzerland'**

Above will provide output only Switzerland only not with "saxon Switzerland"

Thanks
Soni

Comment: Unfortunately that would not work as it would also remove documents with both having Switzerland standing alone and Saxon Switzerland.